# Problem in the manifest of a scene with AR/VR Toolkit

Tags: c#, autodesk

I'm trying to generate a scene with the Autodesk AR/VR ToolKit, but I always get an error in the manifest, when all the requests are processed correctly.

```
    {
        "status": "failed",
        "outputType": "arkit",
        "children": [
            {
                "status": "failed",
                "reason": "unknown",
                "type": "resource",
                "name": "taste2diegoda"
            }
        ],
        "progress": "complete"
    }
]
```

}

The reason is always unknown and I have not found any information.

My object is a .IFC model and is hosted in a permanent bucket, I have obtained the urn from the Autodesk Vcode extension and the blog I am trying to follow is this:

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/arvr-toolkit-refresher

To get the endpoints and the manifest I have used the following functions in python:

```
import base64
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from config.params import *
import os
import json
```

1. First I get a two-legged token:

```
def obtain_token_2_legged():
    # URL de la solicitud POST
    url                 = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token'
    # Encabezados de la solicitud
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Basic {global_id}'
    }

    # Datos del cuerpo de la solicitud
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': f'{all_scope}'
    }

    # Realizar la solicitud POST
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    # Verificar el código de estado de la respuesta
    if response.ok:
        print("La solicitud POST fue exitosa.")
        respuesta_json = response.json()
        return respuesta_json['access_token']
    else:
        print("Error en la solicitud POST:", response.status_code)
        print("Mensaje de error:", response.text)

        return None
```

2. With that token I create a scene:

```
def create_scene(token, urn, name_scene):

    # URL de la solicitud PUT
    url = f'https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/arkit/v1/{urn}/scenes/{name_scene}'

    # Encabezados de la solicitud
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    # Cuerpo de la solicitud
    data = {
        'prj': {
            'urn': f'{urn}'
        }
    }

    # Realizar la solicitud PUT
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    # Verificar el código de estado de la respuesta
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"La solicitud PUT para crear la escena {name_scene} fue exitosa.")
    else:
        print("Error en la solicitud PUT:", response.status_code)
        print(response.text)
```

3. Now I process the scene:

```
def process_scene(token, urn, scene):
    # URL de la solicitud POST
    url = 'https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/job'
    # Encabezados de la solicitud
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    # Datos del cuerpo de la solicitud
    data = {
    "input": {
        "urn": f"{urn}"
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [{
        "type": "arkit",
        "scene": f"{scene}"
        }]
    }
    }

    # Realizar la solicitud POST
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    # Verificar el código de estado de la respuesta
    if response.ok:
        print("La solicitud POST para procesar el estado de la escena fue exitosa.")
        print("Respuesta:", response.json())
    else:
        print("Error en la solicitud POST:", response.status_code)
        print("Mensaje de error:", response.text)
```

4. Scene Manifest

```
def manifest_scene(token, urn):

    # URL de la solicitud GET
    url = f'https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/{urn}/manifest'

    # Encabezados de la solicitud
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    # Realizar la solicitud GET
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    # Verificar el código de estado de la respuesta
    if response.ok:
        print("La solicitud GET para ver el estado de la escena fue exitosa.")
        # Guarda la respuesta en un archivo JSON
        with open('statuts_scene.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(response.json(), f, indent=4)
        print(f"El JSON se ha guardado en el archivo statuts_scene.json ")
    else:
        print("Error en la solicitud GET:", response.status_code)
        print("Mensaje de error:", response.text)
```

All the requests come out correct but in step 4, when I review the response json I always see:

```
......
        {
            "status": "failed",
            "outputType": "arkit",
            "children": [
                {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "reason": "unknown",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "taste2diegoda"
                }
            ],
            "progress": "complete"
        }
    ]
}
```